# Are all function parameters needed?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
udp_discardcb(struct udpcb *up, int isudp)
udp_discardcb(up)

Error:
/usr/src/sys/netinet/udp_usrreq.c:1701:18: error: too few arguments to function
      call, expected 2, have 1
        udp_discardcb(up);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/usr/src/sys/netinet/udp_usrreq.c:274:1: note: 'udp_discardcb' declared here
void
```

Is `int` needed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to include the second argument.  The number of arguments being passed must match the number of parameters in the method/function signature.

i.e.:  `udp_discardcb(up, 1)`